# How to enable SbtWeb in not-play project?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-web

I have a single-project build, implemented in Build.scala file with the following settings: 
`scala
lazy val root = Project(
  id = ProjectInfo.name,
  base = file("."),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings
    ++ Revolver.settings
    ++ Revolver.enableDebugging(port = 5050)
    ++ Twirl.settings
    ++ // more tasks omitted
    ++ Seq(
      mainClass in Compile := Some(launcherClassName),
      mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some(launcherClassName),
      javaOptions in Revolver.reStart ++= List(
        "-XX:PermSize=256M",
        "-XX:MaxPermSize=512M",
        "-Dlogback.debug=false",
        "-Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback.xml"
      ),
      resolvers ++= projectResolvers,
      libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.all,
      parallelExecution in Test := false,
   )
)`

I would like to add sbt-web managed assets processing for the project, as I want to handle coffeescript, less and so on.

I added `sbt-coffeescript` plugin straight to `plugins.sbt` file in `project` folder and actually got it working. So now when I run `web-assets:assets` I have a coffeescript sample file in `/src/main/coffeescript/foo.coffee` and it gets compiled to `target/web/coffeescript/main/coffeescript/foo.js`.

Unfortunately, nothing gets processed when I simply run `compile` or `run` task. How do I enable processing of assets during `compile` in development workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that the old-style of specifying dependencies in projects does not work with AutoPlugins (which is what the WebPlugin is).

Specifically:

```
val foo = Project(
    id = "ok"
    base = file("ok")
    settings = defaultSettings // BAD!
)
```

i.e. if you manually place settings on the Project, you're telling sbt "I Know EVERY setting I want on this project, and I want to completely override the defaults."

The load order of sbt settings is:

1. AutoPlugins  (Core settings now come from AutoPlugins)
2. Settings defined in `Project` instances
3. Settings defined in `build.sbt` files in the base directory of a project.

The above code is re-applying ALL of the sbt default settings from 0.13.x series, which will overwrite anything that the AutoPlugins previously enabled.   This is by design, as any other mechanism wouldn't be "correct".

If you're migrating to using AutoPlugins, simply modify your build to be:

```
lazy val root = Project(
  id = ProjectInfo.name,
  base = file("."))
  settings = 
    // NOTICE we dropped the defaultSettings
    Revolver.settings   
    ++ Revolver.enableDebugging(port = 5050)
    ++ Twirl.settings
    ++ // more tasks omitted
    ++ Seq(
      mainClass in Compile := Some(launcherClassName),
      mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some(launcherClassName),
      javaOptions in Revolver.reStart ++= List(
        "-XX:PermSize=256M",
        "-XX:MaxPermSize=512M",
        "-Dlogback.debug=false",
        "-Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback.xml"
      ),
      resolvers ++= projectResolvers,
      libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.all,
      parallelExecution in Test := false,
   )
)
```

Comment: Josh, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this didn't help – still changes in files under /src/main/assets don't get compiled (but compile command itself notices them and recompiles all the other stuff). Maybe you could take a look at the whole build file and point what am I doing wrong? plugins.sbt: https://gist.github.com/neverov/46e1c2d113efad18bdf6, build.scala: https://gist.github.com/neverov/ecc475df180c2fa907ea

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention, sbt version is 0.13.5.

Answer (score 1):

To run assets generation on compilation I did this:

```scala
settings = ... ++ Seq(
  pipelineStages := Seq(rjs),
  (compile in Compile) <<= compile in Compile dependsOn (stage in Assets),
  // ...
)
```

Than when I run compile, `stage` command is also executed, thus running sbt-web's pipeline.
The question for me is how to make generated assets to become available as part of managed resources (I'm trying to get `sbt-web` working with `xsbt-web-plugin` and `liftweb`)

Comment: Were you successful in getting sbt-web and xsbt-web-plugin working together?  I've been struggling with that for the last day or so and just asked a question that you might be able to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154360/how-can-sbt-web-output-be-used-with-xsbt-web-plugin-via-a-sbt-project-dependency

Comment: Finally I decided that `sbt-web` is monster I don't want to use. For asset management there are far way more convinient and faster (!) tools. Developing with `webpack` was a pleasure. But I didn't get to production use of `webpack` yet.